# Where to put the language translation definition in module based JavaScript architecture?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, translation

At the moment I have constructs like this.

```
id: data[i].id,
headers: ["Även åsnor", "försöker på engelska"],
columns: {
  userName: data[i].firstName + " " + data[i].lastName,
  finishOn: data[i].finishOn !== null 
    ? data[i].finishOn 
    : "pågår..."
  }
```

I want the construct above to be remodeled similarly to this.

```
id: data[i].id,
headers: [Lang.userName, Lang.completedOn],
columns: {
  userName: data[i].firstName + " " + data[i].lastName,
  finishOn: data[i].finishOn !== null 
    ? data[i].finishOn 
    : Lang.holdYourPonnies
  }
```

Then, I could put all the language fields in a separate module and keep them there. I've never done that in JavaScript and I have concerns in that regard.

- Do I need a separate language module for each module that imports it?
- Or should I have a single language module and import it multiple times, once for each module that needs language?
- Or is there a way to import it in the root module and make it available to everybody in the tree?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can export language definitions as an object from JS module or keep them in JSON file. The syntax is basically the same:

```
{
  "FOO": "foo"
}
```

versus

```
export default {
  "FOO": "foo"
}
```

But template literals can be used for multiline strings in JS files, this significantly improves readability.

Most times the support for variables is necessary at some point. Usually a simple template engine is needed. For simplicity and performance template literals can be used here too:

```
export default {
  FOO: "foo",
  BAR: `multiline
        bar`,
  BAZ: (val) => `template baz: ${val}`
}
```

This can be efficiently handled by simplified localization API:

```
import en from './en';
import se from './se';

export class L10n {
  constructor() {
    this.lang = 'en';
    this.definitions = { en, se };
  }

  switch(lang) {
    this.lang = lang;
  }

  get(token, ...templateVars) {
    const val = this.definitions[this.lang][token];

    if (typeof val === 'function')
      return val(...templateVars);
    else
      return val;
  }
}

export default new L10n;
```

And be used like:

```
l10n.get('FOO');
l10n.get('BAZ', 'baz value');
```

Comment: Oh, this looks full-blown pro level. Awesome! I'll wait for a day or two to let others contribute (perhaps there's some more insight that someone else can provide in terms of practical circumstances). But it's definitely +1 for the effort. Remind me in a few days if I've forgotten to accept, won't you? Also - why did you pick *SE* of all the colors of the rainbow?! (It's correct, I'm from Stockholm - just curious. Lucky shot?)

Comment: Sure, I will remind. That's how i18n/l10n is usually handled by the frameworks. You can also check [some framework-agnostic libraries](https://github.com/search?l=JavaScript&o=desc&q=i18n&ref=searchresults&s=stars&type=Repositories). But for what you're asking, no-nonsense ES6 solution is as simple as that. Yes, you can call it a lucky shot, I usually distinguish Scandinavian languages by their diacritics.

Comment: Well, good call. If you see *Å* you can be certain it's Scandic. If you see *Ä* instead of *Æ* or *Ö* instead of *Ø*, you can exclude Danes and Norwegians. Also, if you see verryllooongwoorrrds with a bunch of repeated characters in a row, that's Finnish for sure. Crazy language. Awesome women. But you probably already knew that.   :)

Comment: True. Have some tough time distinguishing Danish, Sweden and Norwegian for the phrases that have no hints from the alphabet, I guess the one should consider learning them instead at this point, hah.